# Microsoft Visual Studio extension (VSIX) lower case $safeprojectname$

Tags: visual-studio-2019, vsix

## Context

I'm developing a Microsoft Visual Studio extension, for which I've seen there are:

- `$projectname$` variable to get the name given to the project,
- `$safeprojectname$` variable to get the name given to the project with all unsafe characters and spaces replaced by underscore.

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/template-parameters?view=vs-2019

For example with project name "Tata yoyo" variables will be:

- `$projectname$ = "Tata Yoyo SWIG"`,
- `$safeprojectname$ = "Tata_Yoyo_SWIG"`.

The extension I'm building is for SWIG projects that will generate Java from C++, and in this context there is a `swig.exe` call that, among others, takes the Java package as parameter, for which I want it to be all lower case, but for now it is `com.company.$safeprojectname$`, then, not necessarily lower case (pointing the obvious: if project name is not lower case, package will not be lower case) and I then have to convert it manually to lower case.

## What I'm looking for

From source page above (and other documentation pages) I've already seen there is no `$lowercasesafeprojectname$` for example, then if anybody knows a way to do it from a function, script or any other way I would be glad.

**Edit**: while I want for this purpose a lower case safe project name I still want to keep the original `$safeprojectname$`, then even if @Ed Dore answer is relevant it is not the solution for me.

In any case, do not hesitate if this is not clear or you want more information.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you implement a [custom wizard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-wizards-with-project-templates) (IWizard) with your template, you can replace the respective token values in the ReplacementsDictionary passed to your [IWizard.RunStarted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.templatewizard.iwizard.runstarted) method, with lowercased equivalents.

Sincerely,

Comment: Thanks for your answer that may help someone, but in my case, it is maybe unclear in my question (I'll update it to be more clear), but I want to keep the original `$safeprojectname$` for some other purposes and create my own parameter with a lower case safe project name.

Comment: Use a custom token ($lowercasesafeprojectname$) in your templated files, and then add that token and it's lowercase value to ReplacementsDictionary passed to your custom IWizard.RunStarted method.